# Silverstripe Backup Module somewhere?

Tags: silverstripe

I didn't see any backup script module for Silverstripe that export database and assets folder into compressed folders. Is anyone have a custom PHP script and execute it with cron job?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/DarrenInwood/silverstripe-backup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [SSPak](https://github.com/silverstripe/sspak), which does exactly what you describe: secure assets as tgz and dump Database.

It can also push the dump on an external server.

You can install it using curl:

```
curl -sS https://silverstripe.github.io/sspak/install | php -- /usr/local/bin
```

and then e.g. run

```
sspak save /var/www /tmp/site.sspak
```

or grab data from a remote server like

```
sspak save me@prodserver:/var/www prod-site.sspak
```

When working remotely you'd need ssh keys or you will be asked for your password a couple of times.